# Chrome's console object

Tags: javascript, json, object

Try to save `amchart` graph into the `localstorage`, but having trouble using the data retrieved back from the storage.

[image]

As it shows here, the original object has this mystery `b` while the new object is normal `object`. In the IE, both display as `[object object]` and i would assume they are the same object. So please someone explain what is this `b` object? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is probably the name of a minified class the original object was an instance of. Structured cloning of non-native objects (something other than `Object`, `Array`, or primitives) does not retain prototype chains, so only "own" properties are kept.